# how to move or copy specific file quantities to other directory

Tags: ubuntu

I would like to know how to move or copy specific number of files to another directory.

For example: If I have 880 files in directory `A` and want to move or copy 150 files from `A` to directory `B` and also 150-300 files from `A` to directory `C`.

I already tried this command

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | head -150 | xargs cp -t "$destdir"
```

But this is copying 880 files to directory `B`

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution to `mv` 150 files:

```
mv `find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type f | head -n 150` "$destdir"
```

Swap out `mv` for `cp` to copy instead.

Here is a test case:

```
mkdir d1 d2
cd d1
touch a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p
cd ../
mv `find ./d1 -type f | head -n 5` ./d2/
```

And the result:

```
ls d1 d2
d1:
b  c  d  e  g  h  i  k  m  n  o

d2:
a  f  j  l  p
```

Edit:

Here is a simple script that will answer your comment:

```
#!/bin/sh
# NOTE: This will ONLY WORK WITH mv.
# It will NOT work with cp.
#
# How many files to move
COUNT=150
# The dir with all the files
DIR_MASTER="/path/to/dir/with/files"
# Slave dir list - no spaces in the path or directories!!!
DIR_SLAVES="/path/to/dirB /path/to/dirC /path/to/dirD"

for d in $DIR_SLAVES
do
    echo "Moving ${COUNT} to ${d}..."
    mv `find ${DIR_MASTER} -maxdepth 1 -type f | head -n ${COUNT}` "${d}"
done

exit
```

NOTE: The sample script has not been tested, but should work.

Comment: for first 150 files will move to B dir but i need second 150 files ie (151-300) to be moved in C dir???

Comment: @SunithaBist See edit. I added a simple script to do that. It may be possible as a single line, but that is what I do and use.

Answer (score 0):

In case your shell supports `process substitution` then you could try this:

The first 150 feiles will be copied over to destdir_B and the NEXT 300 to destdir_C. Any remaining would remain untouched.

```
{
   head -n 150 | xargs -t cp -t "$destdir_B"
   head -n 300 | xargs -t cp -t "$destdir_C"
} <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f)
```

This comes with the usual caveats of not being able to handle exotic filenames.

And when you don't have <(...) you could save find output to a file then redirect that file into the {...}

HTH